# jquery.submit() to POST like .load() with serialized fields

Tags: jquery

I have code like this that works to submit to an MVC controller method that returns a file (download).

```
$('<input />').attr('name', "Email").attr('value', data.Email).appendTo('#form');
$('<input />').attr('name', "LastName").attr('value', data.LastName).appendTo('#form');
$('#form').submit();
```

It works fine, however, "data" is an object with many properties.  Is there a more succinct way of doing this, like .load(url, data), rather than having to append input tags for each property?

Comment: You can use jquery post $.post(url, data, function (response){}); https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I don't have a 'function (response)', since I'm not processing the resonse in the client.  I need to do a normal submit to get back a server response - my controller returns  return File(bytes, "text/xls", "filename.xlsx");